# Imported site collection has "Revert to template"

Tags: master-page, import, export

I've imported a site collection via PowerShell and all the pages show the message:

`The current page has been customized from its template. [Revert to template].`

The original site collection didn't have any modifications to the master page. Why does the import display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is still interpreted as different master page. I would also like to know some 'real' solution for this but so far I only know workaround on how to get rid of this message:

[SharePoint 2010: The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template.](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-current-page-has-been.html)

I have implemented this only once before after masterpage customization.

Comment: Thanks, Vedran. What puzzles me is why this happens when we do an export of an entire site collection. Like you said, it thinks it's a different master page.

Answer (score 2):

Right, it is still interpreted as different master page.

I ran following script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <your intranet site URL>

$list = $web.Lists["Wiki"]

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";

$spQuery.RowLimit = 2000

$caml = '<OrderBy Override="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy>'

$spQuery.Query = $caml 

do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)

    $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

    foreach($item in $listItems)
    {
        $DebugPreferences = "Continue"

        Write-host "Resetting wiki page in site."

        $item.File.RevertContentStream()
    }
}
while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

$web.Dispose()
```

References: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.revertcontentstream(v=office.14).aspx